# When would a program create multiple heaps?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

If and when does c++ trigger the operation of allocating a secondary heap and are there any reasons someone would want to allocate more than one heap? Do any standard actions in c++ like creating a new namespace trigger this, how does the memory handle multiple object with the same name?

Comment: Heaps have nothing to do with namespaces. It is unclear what you're asking, or what exactly you're calling a "heap".

Comment: https://caligari.dartmouth.edu/doc/ibmcxx/en_US/doc/libref/concepts/cumemmng.htm

Comment: "_I know this question is slightly vague_" - why? Why not make it less wague before asking?

Comment: There are two distinct heaps available by default in a C++ program, the one used by `malloc/free` and the one used by `new/delete` https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#mixing-malloc-and-delete. They are not tied to scope or namespaces. There's some [OS support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapcreate?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for multiple heaps, and you can always use a custom allocator, but you shouldn't unless you need something very precise. I don't think this is a bad question because that's not obvious information.

Comment: If I made the title "If and when does c++ trigger the operation of allocating a secondary heap and are there any reasons someone would want to allocate more than one heap? Do any standard actions in c++ like creating a new namespace trigger this, how does the memory handle multiple object with the same name?" it would be too many letters. @TedLyngmo

Comment: Actually that would have been a very elegant way to express it. And you can still edit your question :) @MichaelHearn

Comment: About that that last question: memory allocated on the heap isn't named. The compiler strips away names and boils everything down to memory addresses and stack pointers and such in the assembly code. So it doesn't matter if two pointers to heap memory had the same name in different scopes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Dartmouth_edu article in my comment above there are quite a few time a program may utilize multiple heaps.
"IBM C and C++ Compilers lets you create and use your own pools of memory, called heaps. "

- Good examples are if you think a heap object may corrupt the heap isolate it in its own heap.
- If you allocate a whole heap for a multipart object you can just destroy the heap instead of having to free the memory of every component.
- If you want to do fancy stuff like multithreading! You can also speed up memory access by allowing one thread to free memory from its heap while another is using its own separate heap.

Normal user actions do not create new heaps. Explicitly creating a new heap creates a new heap. 
Namespaces are handled by address memory scopes and pointers. @parktomatomi thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not dictate the use of a heap, much less the use of a secondary heap. That is an implementation detail that is left up to each compiler to determine. As far as the language is concerned, variables can have dynamic [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), but the standard does not say how this is achieved.

In practice, all the compilers I know of do use heap memory for dynamic allocations. In theory, each allocation method (`new` vs. `malloc`) could have its own heap, but there is little reason to complicate memory management by introducing more heaps than necessary. Plus, you shouldn't mix allocation methods. The benefits of multiple heaps tend to depend on manual fine-tuning that is currently beyond the ken of compilers. (A programmer can implement multiple heaps, but that is not the same as "triggering" multiple heaps.)

Namespaces and object names are an unrelated subject, as those do not exist in an executable (unless retained as notes for a debugger).